# Server doesn't listen

Tags: postgresql

My postgreSQL was working fine I created some databases & some tables in it but some day after when I tried to open pgAdmin III it opened fine & require password authentication. I enter the password that I set at the initial time but rather than to open databases it shows the following error message

[image]

And when I tried to open it on browser with this

> localhost:5432

it does not open there too

Comment: You can't just try to go wherever with a browser. Check if the server is actually running. Depends on your operating system how to do that.

Comment: Windows, given the error message. Check the services control panel (`Windowskey-R`, `services.msc`, enter). Is there a PostgreSQL service? Is it running? check the PostgreSQL error logs in the `data\pg_log` directory under your PostgreSQL installation directory. Check the Event Viewer logs.